# How to give shadow and border to tabhost in android?

Tags: android, tabs, border, android-tabhost, shadow

This is my code of tabhost in tabfragment

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
>
 <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" 
        />
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
  />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help in adding shadow in drawable folder to tabhost.Thanks in advance.